# download file from url in gwt

Tags: gwt, download

I want to download a file from internet and I have url of that file . so I wrote a download servlet :

```java
public class DownloadServlet extends HttpServlet {
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws IOException {
        String pathToDownload = request.getParameter("url");

        URL url = new URL(pathToDownload);
        URLConnection uc = url.openConnection();
        String contentType = uc.getContentType();
        int contentLength = uc.getContentLength();
        InputStream is = uc.getInputStream();

        response.setContentType(contentType);
        // resp.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename*=\"utf-8''" + filename + "");
        ServletOutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
        byte[] b = new byte[2048];
        int length;

        while ((length = is.read(b)) != -1) {
            os.write(b, 0, length);
        }
        is.close();
        os.close();
    }
}
```

in this i want to show the popup when user clicks on file whether to save or not so there is

```java
resp.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename*=\"utf-8''" + filename + "");
```

but I want the filename same as filename on internate so additionally what is needed in above snippet?

Answer (score 0):

Cut substring from the last "/" to the end of the URL string - this is your file name.

Answer (score 0):

```
String disposition = httpConn.getHeaderField("Content-Disposition");
            if (disposition != null) {
                // extracts file name from header field

                int index = disposition.indexOf("filename=");
                if (index != 0) {
                    fileName = disposition.substring(index + 9,
                            disposition.length());
                }
            } else {
                // extracts file name from URL

                fileName = link.substring(link.lastIndexOf("/") + 1,
                        link.length());
            }
```